# Datepicker not working on click event

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StartDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '',
            maxDate: '',
            onSelect: function (date) {
                var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
                fun();
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
                $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate");
            }
        }).css('vertical-align', 'top');
});
```

The above code works fine. However if I place the code within textbox click event for example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StartDate").click(function(){
        $(this).datepicker({
          //and the rest......
        });
    })//click
})//ready
```

Then it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I need to perform some functionality within the `onSelect` property of `datepicker` when the textbox is clicked and then display the datepicker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u make it as fiddle ?

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: Your example code is missing closing double-quote: `$("#StartDate`  <==  `).click(function(){`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything to format the date. The DatePicker widget does it for you. Just use the `altField` and `altFormat` properties:

**Demonstration**: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFBn2/10/)

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
// The hidden field to receive the date
altField: "#dateHidden",
// The format you want
altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
// The format the user actually sees
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
onSelect: function (date) {
    // Your CSS changes, just in case you still need them
    $('a.ui-state-default').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how datepicker works. Keep using this binding:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({ });
```

And try this instead:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({ 
    //etc,
    beforeOpen: function(){
        //do your checking here
    },
    onClose: function(){
        //just to show another option
    }
});
```